# Where did I get it wrong on .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, optimization

I need a good Load Time response on my [website](https://espbase.com) and I put this on htaccess.. But am still getting like 1.46 second(s)

And this is already on my htaccess

```
# BEGIN GZIP
BEGIN GZIP COMPRESSION
<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</IfModule mod_gzip.c>
```

Comment: And how did you establish that missing compression is the cause if long load times of whatever resources you publish?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the response is now compressed? But as arkascha suggests, there can be many reasons for slow load times. Compression is just one factor.

Comment: I'd go further than previous comments and say that unless you're serving really large files over a really slow connection, compression is unlikely to be relevant to a load time on the order of 1.5 seconds. Much more likely is that you have some slow processing happening on the server.